# AES CBC mode with CTS in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography

I've just started working on an iOS project in Swift and I need to encrypt and decrypt data using AES in CBC mode with CTS (ciphertext stealing).  I've looked at [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) and [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) but from what I can tell, neither of them support CTS.  I also researched the [Common Crypto](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/) library but it doesn't appear to support CTS, either. I *think* [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/) might be capable of it but I've had multiple people tell me that they had a tough time getting it working properly with Swift.

How can I get CBC with CTS to work for Swift?

Comment: https:///buggreport.apple.com I will be taking to the security team next week about the state of Common Crypto--it sucks,

Comment: @zaph thanks, I'll submit a feature request but I won't get my hopes up.....at least not any time soon.  :-)

Comment: Yeah but they do pay attention to the bug reports and how many are requesting a feature.

Comment: Note: A software implementation such as CryptoSwift is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based methods. Common Crypto uses the hardware encryption capabilities of the device.

Comment: Asking for refs is explicitly off topic on SO, changed the Q somewhat.